# stop Node.js http handler after sending response

Tags: node.js, http, return

```
var http = require('http'); http.createServer(httpHandler).listen(80);

function httpHandler(req, res)
{
    let some_error = 'shit happened'
    if (some_error) http_send_error(req, res)
    console.log('we should not be here if http error sent')
    costly_processing() 
}

function http_send_error(req, res)
{
  res.writeheader(500, 'Content-type: text/plain')
  res.end("something wrong") 
  die() // I have to break this thread and stop handling this request 
}
```

How can I break http request handling after this error message was sent by http?

I can write

```
if (some_error) { http_send_error(req, res); return }
```

or

```
if (some_error) http_send_error(req, res)
else {
     //process without error
}
```

but it looks more verbose and unreadable. How can I break httpHandler after error?

Comment: Hi xoid, will it not exit the handler if you return, following the condition in httpHandler?
```if (some_error) return http_send_error(req, res)```

Comment: Nice!! Make it the answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return the function and it will execute http_send_error before stopping execution in the the handler.

`if (some_error) return http_send_error(req, res)`

Answer (score 0):

as Ikroneman answered:

you can send the error and stop the handler to further process the request just by returning you error function

```
if (some_error) http_send_error(req, res)
```

and in the error handling function no need to "die()"

```
function http_send_error(req, res)
{
  res.writeheader(500, 'Content-type: text/plain')
  res.end("something wrong") 
  // since you return this function in the handler the request handling will stop here
}
```